# Why is createResource error gets undefined on a refetch before it is set

Tags: typescript, solid-js

I want to display the `error` property for a `createResource`.

In this example, why is `error` set to undefined before being thrown.

It logs `undefined` for the error before getting `line error`

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { For, createSignal, createResource, createEffect } from "solid-js";

const p_tau = async () => {
   throw 'line error'
}

function Counter() {
  
  let [s, setS] = createSignal()
  let _r = createResource(s, _ => p_tau())

  setInterval(() => {
     setS(s() + 'h')
  }, 1000)

  createEffect(() => {
     console.log(_r[0].error)
  })

  return (<>
    </>)
}

render(() => <Counter />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=1141676968&version=1.3.16

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the return value of a async function that returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301281/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-a-async-function-that-returns-a-promise)

Comment: I'm not sure what behavior you're expecting, but on the initial effect run, the initial value of the error property is logged, only then does the resource read occur, then the effect is triggered. And then the error property is erased when the resource is triggered again, then after the promise throws. Async functions are always runs after the current synchronous code finishes, that's just js behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `createResource` returns a resource and the initial value for a resource is always `undefined` and remains `undefined` until the promise returned from the fetcher function settles with a value:

```js
import { createEffect, createResource, createSignal } from "solid-js";
import { render } from "solid-js/web";

const fetcher = async () => {
  throw 'line error'
}

function Counter() {

  let [s, setS] = createSignal(1);
  
  let [data] = createResource(s, fetcher)

  setInterval(() => {
    setS(s => s + 1);
  }, 1000)

  createEffect(() => {
    console.log(data(), data.error);
  })

  return (<>
  </>)
}

render(() => <Counter />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Even if you pass a non-null `sourceSignal`, it is same.

The promise resolves to a value in the next tick of the event loop and that is why even if you throw an immediate error, it does not immediately settles with an error. Solid's runtime executes synchronously. Consequently `data.error` receives the error only after the next tick.

Comment: Once settled and error is set, then after a refetch, error is reset to undefined until the fetch resolves and gets a new error value. That's correct right.

Comment: Yes, internally fetcher is called again resulting a state change reflecting the status of the new promise.